# Routing between same network

Tags: cisco, routing

[image]

Hi

In this scenario there is point -to point serial connection between R6 and R7 , there is router R10 whose interface F0/0 is having ip address of 10.1.1.2/24 and there is a host machine (R9) with ip address 10.1.1.1/24 which is running an application,
My problem is that Application on R9  will only work when it will get its Gateway as 10.1.1.1/24 which is of router (R10) , is there any way i can make R6 and R7 transparent for R9 and R10, Or any type of routing using GRE / Route-map or any other way.

Thanks in advace

Comment: Admittedly I don't work with routing equipment very often and it's been a very long time since I've done anything like this but I think that using Integrated Routing and Bridging (IRB) might do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing fancy required here - set up bridge-groups on each router that include f0 and s0 and allow the routers to bridge traffic across the point-to-point link.  [This link](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/11_0/router/configuration/guide/ctb.html#wp2128) is absolutely ancient but the commands haven't really changed and it will get you started.

Comment: hi I had created BVI and configure IRB on both point to point router but i am able to ping R9 to R10 , Can you help me in this.

Comment: Hi Rnxrx , i tried it but not able to route the packet form one network to another network .

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your configuration.  The models of the router in question might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks in advance Rnxrx , We have  cisco 1841 router , and remaining configuration will going to post soon .

Comment: thanks Rmxrx , yes it is working , now i want make serial as sub interface and use bridge group and BVi is it possible to use it subinterface .

Comment: To use a subinterface on the serial side you'll need to switch over the encapsulation from HDLC or PPP to frame-relay (one side set as FR DCE, other side DTE).  That said, I think this is over-complicating things.  If you want to do IRB then you'd need to take the IP's off of the serial and Ethernet and place both in the bridge group, putting each router's IP on the BVI.  No need for subinterfaces, different encapsulations, etc.

Comment: I can not change the configuration on R10 as it is not in my control and between R6 and R7 there are point to point connection so i can not change any one of the router as Frame-relay switch. Thanks in advance Rnxrx

Answer (score 0):

Double-NAT is another option.  My first thought was GRE which was already mentioned.  R9 treats the network on R10's side as a different network and vice versa. R6 source NATs anything from 10.1.1/24 to, say, 10.1.100/24.  R7 source NATs anything from 1.1.2/24 to 10.1.200/24.

To access the app on the R9 from R10's network, you'll go to 10.1.100.1.  The return traffic from R9 heads back to 10.1.200.  R6 and R7 NAT addresses back to the original ones when going back into their respective networks.

No need to add any routes on R9 (host) if default gateway leads back to R6.  The only changes are on R6 and R7 for NAT.  Imagine if R6 and R7 were firewalls with the PTP link between them as the Internet.  Neither side talks directly to the other side's private addresses.  Each side talks to the public addresses of the other.  In my example, someone sniffing traffic on the PTP link (if they could) would see a conversation between 10.1.100.1 and 10.1.200.x.

Comment: but in NAT i think  I will not able to add route on the server R9 that and cant make 10.1.1.2 as gateway ..